# Javascript nested .map() returning multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

Given that I have a `JSON` structure like this:

```
{
    "firstData": [{
        "secondData": [{
            "thirdData": [{
                "value": "whatever"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

And I need to map from `thirdData` `value === "whatever"`

So I am doing

```
 const result = firstData.map(first => {
            return first.secondData.map(second => {
                return second.thirdData.map(third => {
                    return third.value === 'whatever';
                });
            });
        });
```

And this works somewhat fine, but the result is a another deeply nested array (like `[ [ [ {results..} ] ] ])`. I know I can flatten this to a single array by other means, but I feel like I am miss using `.map()`. How can I modify this result to a single array that contains the values of `thirdData` where the value is what ever I want?

The desired result for this would be a single array of `thirdData` objects:

```
[{ value: 'whatever'}, ... {n}]
```

Comment: Could you add in the result you're expecting to get?

Comment: `Array.flapMap()` instead of `Array.map()` if it's supported. Else just flatten the result yourself with something like `.reduce()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a flat result, this isn't a use case for `map`. The simple solution is just to use an array you close over and push to:

```
const result = [];
firstData.forEach(first => {
    return first.secondData.forEach(second => {
        result.push(...second.thirdData.filter(third => third.value === 'whatever'));
    });
});
```

Live Example with a slight extension to your minimal provided data:

```js
const data = {
    "firstData": [{
            "secondData": [{
                "thirdData": [{
                        "value": "whatever",
                        "label": "third #1.1"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "whatever",
                        "label": "third #1.2"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "unrelated",
                        "label": "unrelated"
                    }
                ]
            }]
        },
        {
            "secondData": [{
                "thirdData": [{
                        "value": "another unrelated"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "whatever",
                        "label": "third #2"
                    }
                ]
            }]
        }
    ]
};
const result = [];
data.firstData.forEach(first => {
    return first.secondData.forEach(second => {
        result.push(...second.thirdData.filter(third => third.value === 'whatever'));
    });
});
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Note the `filter` on the `thirdData` and using spread notation to push that data into `result`.

That assumes you want the entry from `thirdData` that has `.value === 'whatever'` rather than a `true`/`false`. If you want the `true`/`false` instead, change that `filter` to `map`.

Or the `for-of` equivalent:

```
const result = [];
for (const first of firstData) {
    for (const second of first.secondData) {
        result.push(...second.thirdData.filter(third => third.value === 'whatever'));
    }
}
```

Live Example with a slight extension to your minimal provided data:

```js
const data = {
    "firstData": [{
            "secondData": [{
                "thirdData": [{
                        "value": "whatever",
                        "label": "third #1.1"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "whatever",
                        "label": "third #1.2"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "unrelated",
                        "label": "unrelated"
                    }
                ]
            }]
        },
        {
            "secondData": [{
                "thirdData": [{
                        "value": "another unrelated"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "whatever",
                        "label": "third #2"
                    }
                ]
            }]
        }
    ]
};
const result = [];
for (const first of data.firstData) {
    for (const second of first.secondData) {
        result.push(...second.thirdData.filter(third => third.value === 'whatever'));
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

(Same note about `filter`/`map`.)

As with all array operations, you can shoehorn this into `reduce`, and I guarantee you you'll get answers primarily using `reduce`, but there's no good reason to use `reduce` here.

```
const result = firstData.reduce((result, first) => {
    return first.secondData.reduce((result, second) => {
        result.push(...second.thirdData.filter(third => third.value === 'whatever'));
        return result;
    }, result);
}, []);
```

Again, though, there's no good reason for that. It's just more complicated.

Live Example with a slight extension to your minimal provided data:

```js
const data = {
    "firstData": [{
            "secondData": [{
                "thirdData": [{
                        "value": "whatever",
                        "label": "third #1.1"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "whatever",
                        "label": "third #1.2"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "unrelated",
                        "label": "unrelated"
                    }
                ]
            }]
        },
        {
            "secondData": [{
                "thirdData": [{
                        "value": "another unrelated"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "whatever",
                        "label": "third #2"
                    }
                ]
            }]
        }
    ]
};
const result = data.firstData.reduce((result, first) => {
    return first.secondData.reduce((result, second) => {
        result.push(...second.thirdData.filter(third => third.value === 'whatever'));
        return result;
    }, result);
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

(Same note about `filter`/`map`.)

Comment: Yes, this is what I am doing now but I am just curious how to do this without defining an result array outside of the loop.

Comment: You could use reduce and declare the result array as the initial value.

Comment: @tjugg - You could abuse `reduce`, but there's no good reason to.

Comment: This won't work with supplied data,.. notices he's array inside array.. :)

Comment: @Keith - What specifically do you think won't work? This does indeed expect arrays within arrays within arrays.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for reducing into a single value(in this case single array) and `Array#forEach` for iterating over the nested array.

```js
const data = {
  "firstData": [{
    "secondData": [{
      "thirdData": [{
        "value": "whatever"
      }]
    }]
  }]
}

const result = data.firstData.reduce((arr, first) => {
  // iterate over the second level array
  first.secondData.forEach(second => {
    // iterate over the third level array
    second.thirdData.forEach(third => {

      // push the value into the result array,
      // change here, in case you want the value 
      //arr.push(third.value === 'whatever');
      
      // in case you need the object then do it like
      if(third.value === 'whatever') arr.push(third);

    });
  });
  // return the array reference for the next iteration
  return arr;

  // set the initial value as an array for the result
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @Keith :  me also not sure, but the output of his code is `[[[true]]]]`

Comment: @Keith :  if he needs the value, then just need to  update following line `arr.push(third.value === 'whatever');`

Comment: Indeed, this is the correct answer for the OP.. :),..  My brain must be in reverse today.. :)  I blame in on the drugs I'm having, must have side effects..